# Currently trying to follow the steps to examine the quickdraw dataset, however, the "qd_read()" function keeps throwing an error. (R)

Tags: r, gsutil, quickdraw

I am using the steps to install the packages as in https://github.com/huizezhang-sherry/quickdraw/ which has worked fine so far. However, as I try to use the qd_read() I keep getting an error

```
octopus <- qd_read("octopus")


Error in gsutil_binary() : failed to find 'gsutil' binary
```

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Seems to be solved here: https://github.com/huizezhang-sherry/quickdraw/issues/1

Comment: I tried that as well but it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue

Comment: You installed the Google Cloud SDK but still get the exact same error that "failed to find 'gsutil' binary"? What OS are you on. Did you restart R? Can you find `gsutil` on your computer? Have you tried adding to to your path?